# ACCESS VBA :run time error 94 invalid use of null

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Private Function getTMD(StartDate, EndDate, StartHour, EndHour) As Double
    
    Dim tempTMD As Integer
    tempTMD = 0
    diffDate = (EndDate - StartDate) - 1
    
If diffDate >= 1 Then
    tempTMD = diffDate * (1080)
    
    If TimeValue(StartHour) > TimeValue("06:00:00") Then
        tempTMD = tempTMD + DateDiff("n", TimeValue(StartHour), TimeValue("23:59:59")) + 1
        Debug.Print tempTMD

    Else
        tempTMD = 1080 + tempTMD
    
    End If
    If (TimeValue(EndHour) > TimeValue("06:00:00") And TimeValue(EndHour) <> TimeValue("23:59:00")) Then
        tempTMD = DateDiff("n", TimeValue("06:00:00"), TimeValue(EndHour)) + tempTMD
      
    ElseIf TimeValue(EndHour) = TimeValue("23:59:00") Then
    
        tempTMD = tempTMD + 1079
    End If
    
ElseIf diffDate = 0 Then
    If TimeValue(StartHour) > TimeValue("06:00:00") Then
        tempTMD = DateDiff("n", TimeValue(StartHour), TimeValue("23:59:59")) + 1 + tempTMD
    Else
        tempTMD = DateDiff("n", TimeValue("06:00:00"), TimeValue("23:59:59")) + 1 + tempTMD
    End If
    
    If TimeValue(EndHour) > TimeValue("06:00:00") And TimeValue(EndHour) <> TimeValue("23:59") Then
        tempTMD = DateDiff("n", TimeValue("06:00:00"), TimeValue(EndHour)) + tempTMD
    ElseIf TimeValue(EndHour) = TimeValue("23:59:00") Then
        tempTMD = tempTMD + 1079
    End If
    
ElseIf diffDate = -1 Then
    If TimeValue(EndHour) > TimeValue("06:00:00") And TimeValue(StartHour) > TimeValue("06:00:00") Then
        tempTMD = DateDiff("n", TimeValue(StartHour), TimeValue(EndHour))
       
    ElseIf TimeValue(EndHour) > TimeValue("06:00:00") And TimeValue(StartHour) <= TimeValue("06:00:00") Then
        tempTMD = DateDiff("n", TimeValue("06:00:00"), TimeValue(EndHour))
    End If
End If
getTMD = Round((tempTMD / 60), 2)

End Function
```

I have this function But i have an error in line

```
If (TimeValue(EndHour) > TimeValue("06:00:00") And TimeValue(EndHour) <> TimeValue("23:59:00")) Then
    tempTMD = DateDiff("n", TimeValue("06:00:00"), TimeValue(EndHour)) + tempTMD
```

I tried to use NZ function but still the error is there.can you helpe me to solve it .?

Comment: Exactly how did you use Nz() - Nz(EndHour, 0) ?

Answer (score 0):

First, this will happen if you pass *Null* values to the function.

To avoid this, declare them as *Date*:

```
Private Function getTMD(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date, StartHour As Date, EndHour As Date) As Double
```

and, if values can be *Null*, decide what value to replace using *Nz*, for example:

```
 Value = getTMD(Nz(StartDate, #00:00#), Nz(EndDate, #00:00#), Nz(StartHour, #00:00#), Nz(EndHour, #00:00#))
```

Next, what you do seems overly complicated, perhaps because of the use of magic numbers. If you try to explain in plain English what the function does, it might be possible to reduce it quite a lot.

Comment: Thanks ,In this function it take a look to date fileds ,if they arenot inthe same month,it should devide in two records , for example 30/06/2020 at 5:35Pm till 2/7/2020 at 14:25 should be in two records  as 30/06/2020 at 5:35Pm till 30/6/2020 at 23:59   and 02/07/2020 at 12:00 am till 2/7/2020 at 14:25  .

Comment: That can only be part of the story. Where does a negative count come from? EndDate can't be earlier than StartDate, I guess. What is it with #06:00 and 1080? And, in your example, why is 2020-07-01 ignored?